# Kubilius model in higher sieve dimension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

The Kubilius model, based on the fundamental lemma of sieve theory, let us approximate the probability of events depending on the variables $X_p$, $p\leq y$, where $X_p=1$ if $p|n$ ($n$ a random integer $\leq x$) and $X_p=0$ if $p\nmid n$, by the probabilities of the corresponding events depending on independent Bernoulli variables $Y_p$, $p\leq y$, where $Y_p=1$ with probability $1/p$ and $Y_p=0$ with probability $1-1/p$.

Kubilius showed that the total variation distance is $O(e^{-c u})$, where $u = \log x/\log y$; Barban and Vinogradov (1964) improved the bound to $O(u^{-u/8} + x^{-1/15})$, and Tenenbaum (1999) improved it to $O_\epsilon(u^{-u} + x^{-1+\epsilon})$.

Question: what if we are dealing with a higher-dimensional situation (in the sense of sieves)? More precisely, say that what we actually want to model is events depending on $X_{p,i}'$, $p\leq y$, $1\leq i\leq \kappa$, where $X_{p,i}'=1$ if $n\equiv a_i \mod p$, and $a_1,\dotsc,a_\kappa$ are fixed integers?

It is clear that one can still define a Kubilius-type model then. The question is whether one can bound the total variation distance by $O(e^{-c u_\kappa})$, or by $O(u_\kappa^{-c u_\kappa} + x^{-c})$, or $O(e^{-c u} + x^{-c})$, for $u_\kappa = \log x/(\kappa \log y)$. Can one?

(A very naïve approach gives a possibly spurious factor of $(\log y)^\kappa$, and thus a bound of $(\log y)^{\kappa} O(e^{9 \kappa - u})$ on the total variation distance, if we use a Brun-based fundamental lemma as in Thm 6.9 of Opera de Cribro.)